# how to use an ImageButton.OnClick if the ImageButton was created in code behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, onclick, code-behind, imagebutton

I created an ImageButton in code behind. Now I need that when a client press the ImageButton, the ImageButton will do a certain function. The problem is that it doesn't do this certain function.

this is the code-

```
var img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "Del" + i.ToString();
img.ImageUrl = "images/1395958363_meanicons_57.png";
img.Width = 48;
img.Height = 38;
img.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.btnForDelete_Click); //doesn't work!!

Lab.Controls.Add(img); //put the image in a label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a callback you want to be triggered upon onClick event:

```
public void DynamicClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
```

Add it to the `Click` `EventHandler` list:

```
img.Click += new EventHandler(DynamicClick);
```

See also: [Setting LinkButton's OnClick event to method in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041137/setting-linkbuttons-onclick-event-to-method-in-codebehind).

Answer (score 2):

EventHandler does not work with LinkButton.
Try the below:

```
img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(onImageClick);
```